# Why is the query_hash zero for EXEC statements?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, extended-events

I'm setting up a monitoring system for SQL Server using Extended Events to find heavy queries as 'production feedback' for our developers. I'm using the events `sp_statement_completed` and `sql_statement_completed`, with predicate filters on cpu_time, logical reads, etc.  I was hoping to aggregate the results on `database_name` and `query_hash` like demonstrated in numerous examples all over the internet, but in the results I see that `query_hash` is 0 for all statements using EXEC, like in the table below (timestamp and queryhash shortened for readability).

```
name                       timestamp      query_hash plan_handle        statement
sql_statement_completed    2016...6414    0          050056019600764... exec Shared.dbo.SyncFirm  
sql_statement_completed    2016...9946    0          06003d00e01e730... exec spSetUserAuth @userid;  
sql_statement_completed    2016...7184    0          0600e30028c9da0... exec spSetUserAuth @userid;  
sp_statement_completed     2016...0409    9826...578 0600c00028e6aa0... SELECT obfuscated_columns FROM dbo.SomeTable
sp_statement_completed     2016...1448    8660...775 060084006d2d660... INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable ( obfuscated_columns)  EXEC(@sql)
sql_statement_completed    2016...7752    0          0600f9006c23f03... exec spSetUserAuth @userid;  
sql_statement_completed    2016...1443    1304...641 06005a0008a9b11... select SUBQ.ontrackstatus, COUNT(SUBQ.ontrac
```

All results do have a value for `plan_handle` and they're all different, so a lot of plans are being generated. Other statements without `query_hash` (that I've seen) include ALTER INDEX, CHECKPOINT, UPDATE STATISTICS, COMMIT TRANSACTION, FETCH NEXT FROM Cursor, some INSERTs, SELECT @variable, IF(@variable = x).

Does anybody know why the `query_hash` is 0? I'm probably missing the point somewhere about the SQL Query Analyzer and EXEC, but I'm not able to find any clues to point me in the right direction. If the results I'm having are 'normal', then how to best aggregate the results?  Wouldn't grouping by statement include literals, whitespace, etc... which is removed when calculating query_hash?

EDIT: as I see it now, `EXEC SomeStoredProcedure`, starts a stored procedure (obvious), and the individual statements in that stored procedure end up in the event session as `sp_statement_completed` events, and those all have a query_hash.

So for `sp_statement_completed` (i.e. 'real' queries), I can aggregate on query_hash and database_name, and for `sql_statement_completed` without query_hash (the EXEC SomeStoredProcedure), I can use the `client_connection_id` to group the statements within a specific execution of a stored procedure, to see what's the most costly part of the procedure.

Comment: I don't know why `query_hash` is 0 but as for why `exec spSetUserAuth @userid;` rows have different plan handles: `The algorithms to match new SQL statements to existing, unused execution plans in the cache require that all object references be fully qualified.` ([Source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181055(v=sql.105).aspx).) If all those entries were e.g. `exec dbo.spSetUserAuth @userid;`, you might get identical plan handles for them.

Comment: They have different plan_handles because they are used in different databases, I didn't notice that at first. In that case, the object references aren't the same, hence the different plans. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: If that's the case wouldn't that solve your problem? You could generate reports on activity by database, and you would be able to detect parameter sniffing/parametrization issues with certain procedures.

Comment: Well, yes actually...

Comment: If your underlying problem has indeed been solved, could you post an answer explaining your findings and how that helped to solve the problem? You don't have to but, if this can inspire you in any way, that could be a valuable contribution to this site's knowledge base. Keep in mind that we prefer to keep comments around for as long as they help to clarify the question/answer, so feel free to repeat any points already mentioned in these comments so that they can later be safely removed.

Comment: OK, will do. I'm quite busy now, so it might take a few days before I can flesh it out a bit.  Thanks!

Comment: @BertVanLandeghem  Please don't post potential answers in your question. If you have an answer, please post it as such :)

Additionally, I posted a solution I found in a optimization book I had.

Answer (score 1):

**To explain why the hash is created:**

When we submit a query to the server, the algebrizer (yes that's what it is called) process creates a hash, like a coded signature, of the query. The hash is a unique identifier. An identifier is unique for any given query, including all the text that defines the query, including spaces and carriage returns, the optimizer compares the hash to queries in the cache. If a query exists in the cache that matches the query coming into the engine, the entire cost of the optimization process is skipped and the execution plan in the plan cache is reused.

`EXEC` starts a stored procedure which can have its code change, since SQL Server knows that it does not need to compare `EXEC` to optimize it, SQL Server does not create a hash.